# JGit connect to separate git repository by .git-file

Tags: java, git, jgit

I used `"git init --separate-git-dir=C:/repo/.git"` and define another location for the repository.
My work location is `"C:/work/"`.

In the work location git creates a `.git-file` with linking to the repo location.

When i use JGit i can not connect to my repo:

```java
Git
   .open(new File("C:\\work\\.git"))
   .reset()
   .setMode(ResetType.HARD)
   .call();
```

Then i get an exception:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException: repository not found: C:\work\.git
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.build(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git.open(Git.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git.open(Git.java:99)
    at de.test.git.App.main(App.java:20)
```

How to connect to my repository?

Thanks for help.

Edit:

Thanks to Joni who found a solution for my issue.

> Thank you Joni! You are awesome! I tried it like you wrote with
> setting  the work tree and it works like a charm. By the way i found
> an option to do this steps without to know where the repo location is.
> For those who are interesed:

```java
Repository repo = new FileRepositoryBuilder() 
   .findGitDir(new File("C:\\work"))
   .setWorkTree(new File("C:\\work"))
   .build(); 

Git git  = new Git(repo); 
git
   .reset()
   .setMode(ResetType.HARD)
   .call(); 
git.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've correctly cloned your repository into `C:\work`? Can you confirm  with another tool that it is consistent? Also please try `new File("C:\\work")` and let JGit discover your `.git` directory itself

Comment: I did not cloned the repository. I created with git init a new local one and with --separate-git-dir i linked to the repo location. In my work location there is only a .git-file (not the repository). I tried ```new File("C:\\work")``` but it did not work, too.

Comment: When i use Git Bash on Windows in the work location i am able to use ```git reset --hard``` while Git Bash is also able to connect to the repository. Only JGit can not connect to the repository through the linked ".git-file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that JGit does not (yet) support the `--separate-git-dir` option.

As a work-around, you can open the linked repo directly:

```
Git
   .open(new File("C:/repo/.git"))
   .reset()
   .setMode(ResetType.HARD)
   .call();
```

When used like this, JGit won't know where your working directory is so I imagine anything that has to do with the working directory will fail. Going by [the user guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide) you can create a customized `Repository` object like this:

```
FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File("C:/repo/.git"))
  .setWorkTree(new File("C:/work"))
  .readEnvironment() // scan environment GIT_* variables
  .build();
```

And then use the `Git(Repository)` constructor instead of `Git.open`:

```
Git git = new Git(repository);
git.reset()
   .setMode(ResetType.HARD)
   .call();
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea! I tried to open the repo directly and it worked. But there is another problem. On reset the work location will not be resetted. Only the repo itself will be resetted and git paste the resetted files into the repo location relative to the .git-directory.

Comment: Thank you Joni! You are awesome! I tried it like you wrote with setting the work tree and it works like a charm. By the way i found an option to do this steps without to know where the repo location is. For those who are interesed: ```  Repository repo = 
    new FileRepositoryBuilder()
    .findGitDir(new File("C:\\work"))
    .setWorkTree(new File("C:\\work"))
    .build();

  Git git = new Git(repo);
  git.reset().setMode(ResetType.HARD).call();
  git.close(); ```